# NHibernate query with FetchMany returns incorrect results

Tags: nhibernate

I have two related entities: **Job** and **Group**, with a **Many-To-Many** relationship.

I am performing a simple query to retrieve a specific Job and it's associated Group (through the **GroupRecipients** property):

```
var job = jobsRepo.Get()
                .Where(j => j.Id == jobKey.Id)
                .FirstOrDefault();

var countA = job.GroupRecipients.Count;
```

The result of which is **countA==2**, which corresponds to the state in the database.

The first weirdness occurs when I add a FetchMany:

```
var job = jobsRepo.Get()
                .FetchMany(x => x.GroupRecipients)
                .Where(j => j.Id == jobKey.Id)
                .FirstOrDefault();

var countB = job.GroupRecipients.Count;
```

This results in **countB==1**. Only one item appears in the job.GroupRecipients collection, which contradicts the state in the database.

But it get's even more interesting. If I run the following in succession:

```
var job = jobsRepo.Get()
                .Where(j => j.Id == jobKey.Id)
                .FirstOrDefault();

var countA = job.GroupRecipients.Count;

var jobB = jobsRepo.Get()
                .FetchMany(x => x.GroupRecipients)
                .Where(j => j.Id == jobKey.Id)
                .FirstOrDefault();

var countB = jobB.GroupRecipients.Count;
```

Then I get **countB==2**, the expected result. Removing the line with countA again causes **countB==1**.

Some more info:
I perform the queries in a **transaction** in a **stateless session**.
The version of NHibernate is **3.3.1**

**The two issues can thus be summarized as following:**

1. FetchMany returns partial results
2. One query is dependent on another query in an unexpected way.

**Any explanation of this behavior is very welcome.**

Comment: i thought stateless session can not lazyload collections. could you please post the jobsrepo.Get() Method plz?

Comment: Here are some more explanations: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6392490

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug or mismatch in the way the LINQ provider handles `FirstOrDefault` - on mine, it appears to add a blanket `LIMIT 1` to the query, which obviously doesn't work with the eager loading (which results in an `OUTER JOIN`).

I've solved it by explicitly converting to an enumerable in the middle:

```
var job = jobsRepo.Get()
                  .FetchMany(x => x.GroupRecipients)
                  .AsEnumerable()
                  .FirstOrDefault(j => j.Id == jobKey.Id);
```

Which is a bit of a hack, but solves the problem.

Likely, your second example works because the first loads the entity into the cache, and so nHibernate doesn't feel the need to go to the database (and encounter the faulty logic in the LINQ provider).

Comment: In this example you are pulling back every job (and associated GroupRecipient) and doing the FirstOrDefault in memory.  I believe you could throw a .Where just prior to the FetchMany to at least restrict that a bit.  http://charlass.wordpress.com/2012/03/11/nhibernate-firstordefault-and-fetch-not-what-i-expect/

Comment: Do you know if this bug was solved in any version of nhibernate?

Comment: .SingleOrDefault() also works. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380494/nhibernate-why-does-linq-first-force-only-one-item-in-all-child-and-grandchil?noredirect=1&lq=1